# Oracle Datasource invalid or stale object exception

Tags: java, spring, oracle, connection-pooling

I have a connection cache pool created and occasionally I get the `Invalid stale connection object` error. When I refresh the page and do the same operation it is working fine, means the exception is gone.

This is my config for the connection pool,

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="URL" value="${jdbcUrl-myapp}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbcUsername-myapp}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbcPassword-myapp}" />
        <property name="connectionProperties">
            <value>
                oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
            </value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <props merge="default">
                <prop key="MinLimit">0</prop>
                <prop key="MaxLimit">100</prop>
                <prop key="InitialLimit">1</prop>
                <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">600</prop>
                <prop key="InactivityTimeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="ValidateConnection">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` instead? Also make sure you have proper tx setup and that you don't open connections yourself.

Comment: I know OracleConnectionPoolDataSource is a new API but is there any known issues with using OracleDataSource like mine? Also what you mean by proper tx setup? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to get ride of invalid/stale connection.

Try following set of properties:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="URL" value="${jdbcUrl-myapp}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbcUsername-myapp}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbcPassword-myapp}" />
    <property name="connectionProperties">
        <value>
            oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <props merge="default">
            <prop key="MinLimit">0</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">100</prop>
            <prop key="InitialLimit">1</prop>
            <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">600</prop>
            <prop key="InactivityTimeout">300</prop>
            <prop key="ValidateConnection">true</prop>
            <prop key="testOnBorrow">true</prop>
            <prop key="testOnReturn">true</prop>
            <prop key="testWhileIdle">true</prop>
            <prop key="validationQuery">select 1 from dual</prop>
            <prop key="removeAbandoned">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```